# How do I convert a Detectron2 model into another deeplearning framework?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, onnx, tensorrt, detectron

I would like to  convert a detectron2 model into a another deeplearning framework i.e. PyTorch, TensorFlow or ONNX. How do I do this conversion?

I can run inference on the detectron2 model with the `cfg` (which I believe means config in detectron2 lingo).

The goal is to eventually run the Detectron2 model on a Nvidia Jetson Board. So, the goal would be to convert the model.

Comment: I believe detectron2 is implemented in pytorch already. I don't really understand your question

Comment: Did you figure it how? Based on this issue, it seems that it is not supported. is it? https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [v0.4](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/releases/tag/v0.4) you can deploy detectron2 models to torchscript and ONNX. There is more information about it in the [documentation](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/deployment.html) (and also example code).